# TypeError Running jQuery Code Snippet

Tags: jquery

I am newbie in jQuery. 
I have the following code snippets from a book am reading. I try to run it but get the following error .

**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"**

I used console.log() and  found that the object/element given to the "ajaxValidation()" is undefined. The error comes from the "ajaxValidation() " . The "$(this)" is given as the argument inside the document.ready() event but i receive TypeError. The idea behind the code is that when a key is pressed in one of the "required"  text-field, that text-field is given to the "ajaxValidation()" in the form of "$(this)" for validation.

```
     var ajaxValidation = function(obj){

                var $this = $(obj);
                var param = $this.attr('name');
                var value = $this.val();
                $.get("inputValidation.php", {'param':param, 'value': value}, function(data){
                    if(data.status == "OK"){
                        validationRequiredInputs();
                    }else {
                        $this.addClass('failed');
                    }
                }, "json");
            }


 var validationRequiredInputs = function(){
        var numberOfMissingInputs = 0;
        $('.required').each(function(index){
            var $item = $(this);
            var itemValue = $item.val();
            if(itemValue.length){
                $item.removeClass('failed');
            }else {
                $item.addClass('failed');
                numberOfMissingInputs++;
            }
        });

    $(document).ready(function(){
            var timerId = 0;
            $('.required').keyup(function() {
                clearTimeout (timerId);
                timerId = setTimeout(function(){
                    ajaxValidation($(this));
                }, 200);
            });
        });
```

The html form is::

```
<form class="simpleValidation">
    <div class="fieldRow">
        <label>Title *</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="fieldRow">
        <label>Url</label>
        <input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="http://" />
    </div>
    <div class="fieldRow">
        <label>Labels</label>
        <input type="text" id="labels" name="labels" />
    </div>
    <div class="fieldRow">
        <label>Text *</label>
        <textarea id="textarea" class="required"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldRow">
        <input type="submit" id="formSubmitter" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**1)** Can you tell me what is causing the problem?

**2)** Can someone also explain to me why there is "$" infront of the "obj" argument inside the "ajaxValidation()"?

Please all the code above is from the book am reading. I am a newbie learning jQuery.

thanks

Comment: Re 2: That `$(obj)` is intended to convert a DOM element parameter to a jQuery object, but in your code that is being done on the call to `ajaxValidation` by `$(this)`. One or the other can go (calling `$()` on an existing jQuery object does not cause any damage though).

Comment: Re 1: Where is the `toLowerCase` failing (as that is not directly referenced in your code)?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I think the toLowerCase is something that happens internally maybe through the prototype. I don't need to add that to the code.

Comment: Just spotted a problem with your `setTimeout` call. Try the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Re 1:

The following code uses the wrong `this` inside the `setTimeout` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var timerId = 0;
        $('.required').keyup(function() {
            // Keep a copy of the object that caused the event
            var THIS = this;
            clearTimeout (timerId);
            timerId = setTimeout(function(){
                // Pass the DOM object that caused the event ($() is not needed here)
                ajaxValidation(THIS);
            }, 200);
        });
    });
```

`this` inside of a `setTimeout` call is actually the object that made the call (in this case `this` is probably `window`).

### Re 2:

That `$(obj)` is intended to convert a DOM element parameter to a jQuery object, but in your code that is being done on the call to `ajaxValidation` by `$(this)`. One or the other can go (calling `$()` on an existing jQuery object does not cause any damage though). e.g. you can have `$($($('#test')))` and that is the same as `$('#test')`.